# How to check if an id (inside a list of ids) exists in an array of objects with ids?

Tags: javascript, node.js

List1:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

List2:

```
[{id:1,name:hi},{id:3,name:hi},{id:5,name:hi}]
```

How can I check which items from List1 is missing from List2?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. What have you tried?

Comment: i've tried nothing and i'm all outta ideas. sorry, im a java background, so still learning the ropes of js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this with help of **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  list2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'hi'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'hi'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'hi'
  }];

// get array of id's
var ids = list2.map(function(v) {
  return v.id;
})

// get missing elements
var miss = list1.filter(function(v) {
  // check element in id's array
  return ids.indexOf(v) == -1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(miss, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

Using ES6 arrow function

```js
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  list2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'hi'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'hi'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'hi'
  }];

// get array of id's
var ids = list2.map(v => v.id);

// get missing elements
var miss = list1.filter(v => ids.indexOf(v) == -1);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(miss, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.prototype.filter`

```js
var list1 = [1,2,3,4];
var list2 = [{id:1,name:'hi'},{id:3,name:'hi'},{id:5,name:'hi'}];

var t = list2.map(e => e.id); // get all 'ids' from 'list2'

var result = list1.filter(e => t.indexOf(e) == -1);

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: OP is asking: "which items from List1 are missing from List2?". In your demo it should be [2, 4]. I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to reduce list2 to array of missing ids. Maybe like this:

```js
var data = [{id: 1, name: 'hi'}, {id: 3, name: 'hi'}, {id: 5, name: 'hi'}]
var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]

var missing = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.filter(function(id) { return id !== curr.id })
}, ids.slice())

document.write(missing)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with linear complexity for sorted arrays.

```js
var list1 = [1, 2, 4, 30],
    list2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'hi' }, { id: 3, name: 'hi' }, { id: 5, name: 'hi' }],
    missing = list1.filter(function (a) {
        while (list2[this.index] && list2[this.index].id < a) {
            this.index++;
        }
        return !list2[this.index] || list2[this.index].id !== a;
    }, { index: 0 });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(missing, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I think that complexity is O(n^2), isn't ?
O(n) - filter function * O(n) - whille loop

Comment: the filter loops one time, it's O(n). the while loop loops only once until it reaches the end. so here O(m). togehter : O(n + m) --> linear.

Comment: why `+`? `while` loop is inside of filter function and that should be `*` - O(n * m)

Comment: it is because `this.index` is keeping the value.

Comment: btw, it won't work when `list1` is `[1, 2, 30, 4]` or `[1, 2, 4, 30]`

Comment: @isvforall, yes, see above *sorted array*.

Comment: `[1, 2, 4, 30]` is sorted?

Comment: @isvforall, the issue with `undefined` values is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

Combine Array methods `filter` and `some`:

```
var list1 = [1,2,3,4];
var list2 = [{id:1,name:'hi'},{id:3,name:'hi'},{id:5,name:'hi'}];
return list2.filter(function(o) {
    return !list1.some(function(id) { return o.id === id; })
})
```

which yields the objects from `list2` whose ids are not in `list1`.

The converse, as I saw many people post, is this:

```
return list1.filter(function(id) {
     return !list2.some(function(o) { return o.id === id; });
});
```

which yields the ids from `list1` that do not have corresponding objects in `list2`